# Moving views in RelativeLayout when zooming ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, drawing, zooming, android-relativelayout

In my application I draw markers on a floor plan, but right now I draw them on the floor plan image and display it in an ImageView. The problem is the resolution of those markers, since the user has to zoom in and when the markers have to keep the same size they will have to be resized to a smaller resolution.

So when you are zoomed in the markers get very pixelated, because of the resolution of the image.

I was thinking that I could create seperate views for each marker and put all of the views in a RelativeLayout, so I could position them relative to the ImageView when zooming in and out so the markers would keep the correct size.

Is this even possible or is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: so draw your markers only in the original size: do not draw them scaled

Comment: Don't you need a coordinate system to position the markers instead of a `RelativeLayout`? And how about using a view to draw on and putting your ImageView into the same view group/layout as this drawing view?

Comment: @pskink I don't want them to be the same size all the time. I want them to be resized so that they keep the same size relative to the screen not relative to the ImageView, if that makes sense?

Comment: so draw them in one size depending on original size and screen size

Comment: @KalaBalik Yeah, I have coordinates, but was thinking that I would add the ImageView and the separate marker ImageViews to a RelativeLayout and would position markers so that they would follow they coordinate in the ImageView when zooming. Did you mean something like that or am I wrong? :-)

Comment: Maybe an AbsoluteLayout is better?

Comment: just override `onDraw` in your custom `ImageView` and draw your markers here

Comment: @pskink yeah, that's what I'm doing at the moment, but the problem is that the resolution of the Image (floor plan) is too low for the markers to be in a good resolution when zoomed in. This is the case, because I draw the markers relative to the zoom factor so that they keep the same size relative to the screen while zooming.

Comment: so draw them in fixed size, do not draw them scaled depending on current zoom factor

Comment: @pskink but that's exactly what I want. I just want the markers to be in a good resolution always but in a size that is always the same relative to the screen. So that's why I was thinking that the solution would be different views. Am I wrong?

Comment: ok if your zoom == 1, the markers are 64x64, what size should they have when zoom == 2? 128x128?

Comment: @pskink If the scale of the drawing is 2 the markers should be 32x32, so that's why there is a problem with resolution and why I was thinking that keeping each marker in a seperate view that just is an overlay would be better.

Comment: so i dont understand it at all: you are making zoom in, everything is larger on your floor plan (zoom factor == 2) and the markers should be smaller??

Comment: @pskink It's like when looking at Google Maps for example. The markers still are the same size when zooming in.

Comment: so they should be 64x64 all the time, no matter what zoom factor is applied? if so this is what i am saying: do not draw them scaled, draw them only with one fixed size

Comment: @pskink Yeah, but this only works when they are not drawn onto the image, since they get bigger relative to the screen when zooming in on the image, if they are always 64x64 and are part of the image and not seperate views.

Comment: what gets bigger? just override onDraw and draw them in any size you like

Comment: @pskink Yeah, but the size of the bitmap is the size of the floor plan image and so this determines the resolution of the image that the markers get drawn onto, which means that they get pixelated most of the time when zooming in and drawing them in the size I want.

Comment: [here](http://pastebin.com/JkMLHq5e) you have a custom `ImageView` which creates a "marker" of size ImageView.getWidth() / 4 no matter how big your floor plan is and no matter what zoom factor you use, all you need is to draw your markers inside `onDraw` method

Comment: and the output of that custom `ImageView` would look like [this](http://pasteboard.co/26w8WQxiZ.jpg), is it what you want?

Comment: @pskink Yes, exactly like that!

Comment: so as i said: `all you need is to draw your markers inside onDraw method`

Comment: @pskink Sorry for not responding! I will try it out immediately. But doesn't the canvas have a resolution that is the same as the bitmap that has been set to the ImageView or how does that work?

Comment: `But doesn't the canvas have a resolution that is the same as the bitmap that has been set to the ImageView` what do you mean? what resolution? try to draw anything inside `onDraw` and you will see how it is drawn

Comment: Nevermind, I was thinking about it wrong. It works now. If you post it as an answer I will set it as the correct answer! :-) Thank you for being patient with me ;-)

Comment: so how do you know where to draw the markers om the `Canvas`?